# Hessian with rank one

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix, rank-1-matrices

Let $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{H}}$ be the Hessian of the function $F(\boldsymbol{x})$. If this function is of the form
$$
F(\boldsymbol{x}) = f(\hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}}\cdot\boldsymbol{x})
$$
with some unit vector $\hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}}$ and function $f$, then
$$
\mathsf{H}_{ij} = \hat{\omega}_i\,\hat{\omega}_j\,f''(\hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}).
$$
In particular, $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{H}}$ has rank one everywhere with the only non-trivial eigenvector being $\hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}}$.

My question, is the reverse also true? That is, if $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{H}}$ has rank one everywhere, is then necessarily $F(\boldsymbol{x})$ of the form above?

Answer (score -1):

No; take as a 2D example:

$$F(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1901844)

Comment: @KamalSaleh; did you read the question and my answer? His question is whether the converse holds to which I replied: "No" and provided a counterexample!

Comment: Yes I did. However, answers need to be high quality. There are many comments that are like your answer, all throughout stack exchange.